# Zend Framework - Param not specified

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I got a little problem here. I'm currently trying to use the Zend Router Rewrite but I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Router_Exception' with message 'alias is not specified'
```

Here's my code for the route:

```
// BLOG -> CATEGORIES -> LIST ARTICLES
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '/blog/categories/:alias',
    array(
        'module'     => 'blog',
        'controller' => 'categories',
        'action'     => 'list'
    )
);
$router->addRoute('blog-categories-list', $route);
```

The URL i'm trying to access is: `/blog/categories/general/`.

Why am I getting this error?

P.S.: I didn't specify a default value for `:alias` 'cause I have this route also:

```
// BLOG -> CATEGORIES
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'blog/categories/',
    array(
        'module'     => 'blog',
        'controller' => 'categories',
        'action'     => 'index'
    )
);
$router->addRoute('blog-categories', $route);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably coming from somewhere where you are trying to output a link using the route, such as the URL helper:

```
$this->url(array(), 'blog-categories-list')
```

It's telling you that you need to pass 'alias' to this as well.